# CsvHelper C# WriteRecords

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I mapped a csv file in a class, suppose it's called A made this way

```
  public class A {
      private string field1;
      private string field2;
   }
```

When I invoke the **writeRecords** method I would like to reverse the order of the fields eg I would like to write field 2 first and then field 1 it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom `ClassMap<A>` and provide the indexes for each property:

```
public class A_Mapper : ClassMap<A>
{
    public A_Mapper()
    {
        Map(a => a.field1).Index(1);
        Map(a => a.field2).Index(0);
    }
}
```

To make it work you need to register this mapper to the configuration:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
using (CsvWriter csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
{
    csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<A_Mapper>();
    csv.WriteRecords(aList);
}
```

Documentation: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/2.x/

Answer (score 2):

Well, a quick Google Search for CsvHelper gives me a pretty well written documentation page for it: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/2.x/

You can either do it the simple way, and use the writeRecord method instead, within a for statement, writing records in whatever order you want, or, you could create custom maps for it. Anyway, see the documentation for examples.